# ngx-bootstrap/datepicker not rendering and generating error BsDatepickerDirective -> BsDatepickerConfig

Tags: angular, datepicker, ngx-bootstrap

I just go through [ngx-bootstrap](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker) for datepicker control for my basic Angular app but stuck with below error

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[BsDatepickerDirective -> BsDatepickerConfig]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[BsDatepickerDirective -> BsDatepickerConfig]:
```

snippet from **app.module.ts**

```
import { BsDatepickerModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/datepicker';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    BsDatepickerModule.forRoot()
```

This is html snippet

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="doj">DOJ:</label>
            <input type="text" bsDatepicker  
            formControlName="DOJ" class="form-control" name="doj" id="doj">
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add BsDatepickerConfig to providers:[] in the app modules, that worked for me